# implementation of cascade save in spring data and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm implementing a application based on spring data and mongodb.

### QATemplate.java

```
@Document(collection = "QATemplate")
public class QATemplate {

    @Id
    private String titleId;

    public String getTitleId() {
        return titleId;
    }

    public void setTitleId(String titleId) {
        this.titleId = titleId;
    }

    @Field("title")
    private String title;

    @Field("tags")
    private Object tags;

    @Field("answer_type")
    private String answerType;

    @Field("answer")
    @DBRef
    @CascadeSave
    private Object answer;
```

i have a field which can be simple text or can be embedded document. 
so i created that field as a object type.

```
    @Field("answer")
    private Object answer;
```

It worked fine.
but i need to save embedded document with its own id and pass its id as reference into this document so i have to write my code like this

```
    @Field("answer")
    @DBRef
    @CascadeSave
    private Object answer;
```

for implementation of cascade save i used

### CasecadeSave.java

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface CascadeSave {

}
```

### CasecadeCallback.java

```
public class CascadeCallback implements ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback {

    private Object source;
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public CascadeCallback(final Object source, final MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        this.source = source;
        this.setMongoOperations(mongoOperations);
    }

    @Override
    public void doWith(final Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);

        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(DBRef.class) && field.isAnnotationPresent(CascadeSave.class)) {
            final Object fieldValue = field.get(getSource());

            boolean insta = !(fieldValue instanceof String);
            boolean instanull = fieldValue != null;

            if ( instanull && insta ) {
                final FieldCallback callback = new FieldCallback();
                ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(fieldValue.getClass(), callback);
                getMongoOperations().save(fieldValue);
            }
        }
    }

    public Object getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(final Object source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public MongoOperations getMongoOperations() {
        return mongoOperations;
    }

    public void setMongoOperations(final MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations;
    }
}
```

### CascadeSaveMongoEventListener.java

```
public class CascadeSaveMongoEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Object> {

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    @Override
    public void onBeforeConvert(final Object source) {
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(source.getClass(), new CascadeCallback(source, mongoOperations));
    }
  }
```

### FieldCallback.java

```
public class FieldCallback implements ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback {
    private boolean idFound;

    @Override
    public void doWith(final Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);

        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Id.class)) {
            idFound = true;
        }
    }

    public boolean isIdFound() {
        return idFound;
    }
}
```

but after applying this code if i insert json data like this

```
{
    "title":"Indiaa",
    "answerType":"text",
    "answer":[
            {
                 "title":"Indiaana jones",
                 "answerType":"text",
                 "answer":"testing vvv"
            }
        ]
}
```

i got an error:

```
threw exception [Request processing failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBList] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBList
```

and if i try to insert json data like this:

```
{
    "title":"Indiava",
    "answerType":"text",
    "answer":"vv"
}
```

I got an error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No mapping metadata found for class java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `DBRef`, instead of saving the your `answer` object inside `QATemplate`, you're saving only a reference to it, but it's in another collection:

```
{ "$ref" : "COLLECTION", "$id" : ObjectId("someobjectID") }
```

Moreover, you say you want to have an answer "document" but you actually pass first an array and later a simple string.

To get it running, create a type that encompasses both an answer document and a string answer. That way `Spring Data MongoDB` will know in which collection to put it. At first try with just a document, like this:

```
{
    "title":"Where is India",
    "answerType":"text",
    "answer":{
        "text":"Asia"
    }
}
```

Where `answer` is:

```
@Field("answer")
@DBRef
@CascadeSave
private Answer answer;
```

And `Answer` is:

```
@Document(collection = "Answers")
public class Answer {
    @Id
    private String id;

    String text;
}
```

Once this is running turn `Answer` into an interface and then have a `TextAnswer` (simple text) or `FullAnswer` (a whole answer document). Polymorphism is supported in `Spring Data MongoDB`.

Comment: as per my requirement answer is not predefined it can be string or QATemplate. in case of string only single document should create but in case of QATemplate should save all subdocument and pass its reference in main document.

Comment: In your suggested answer for each time when answer is TextAnswer it will create an document for answer only and make its reference in main document. i.e. saving two different documents. but i want to save only a document in case of string.